# Feeds: Is it possible to set a unique field other than the title field?

Tags: entities, feeds

I'm trying to create a feed importer that uses a unique ID that is NOT necessarily in the title field of the content type. For example, were I using the feeds importer to import a list of contacts, I'd like to have the unique ID be the phone number, yet I would prefer that the content title be the name of the contact rather than the phone number, for organization and aesthetic purposes. Is this possible? As of now, it seems I am limited to enabling only the title field as unique.

I realize I could simply put the contact name into the title field and set that as unique, but this is less prudent, as contacts may have identical names and similarly with my data, the duplicity of titles and/or misspellings is/are inevitable. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For most of my Feeds, I import the Node ID and make that unique.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that will allow me to update the content nodes for which I am continually importing data. If I allow the NID to be unique, I will simply get new content with every upload, where I'd like to update existing nodes.

Comment: You will only get new content when a row in your feed has a blank NID value. If a row contains a valid NID, the corresponding node will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Look at [Support unique targets in mappers](https://www.drupal.org/node/661606).